# How to test code with Jest that uses readonly fields on mocks of libraries (such as ws socket.readyState)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking

I want to unit test this **JS** code with **Jest**. It's using the ws websocket library:

Socket.js

```
import WebSocket from "ws";

export default class Socket {
    socket = undefined;

    connect(url): void {
        if (this.socket !== undefined && this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            throw new Error("Socket is already connected");
        }

        this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
    }
}
```

I want to check the error is thrown. For that to happen, I create a mock for the socket and then need to set the `readyState` of the socket object to `CLOSED`. The issue is that this is impossible because it's a readonly field.

Test:

```
import Socket from "./Socket";
import WebSocket from "ws";

jest.mock("ws");

it("can connect", () => {
    // Arrange
    const url = "www.someurl.com";
    jest.spyOn(global, "Promise").mockReturnValueOnce({} as Promise<void>);

    const sut = new Socket();

    // Act
    sut.connect(url);

    const webSocket = jest.mocked(WebSocket).mock.instances[0];

    // Set readystate of socket
    webSocket.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSED; // Error here: Cannot assign to 'readyState' because it is a read-only property. ts(2540)

    const action = () => sut.connect(url);

    // Assert
    expect(action).toThrowError(new Error("Socket is already connected"));
});
```

**Question**: How to test any code that uses readonly fields on mocks of libraries such as `socket.readyState`?

**Edit:** Added the mvce on request above.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code can't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better test strategy is to create a test WebSocket server and connect it. This is also the official team doing, see some [test cases](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/test/websocket.test.js#L490). Mocking `ws` and testing the implementation details is not recommended.

Below testing code using TypeScript:

`socket.ts`:

```
import WebSocket from "ws";

export default class Socket {
  socket!: WebSocket;

  connect(url: string): void {
    if (this.socket !== undefined && this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      throw new Error("Socket is already connected");
    }
    this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
  }
}
```

`socket.test.ts`:

```
import WebSocket from "ws";
import Socket from "./socket";

describe('74062437', () => {

  test('should connect the websocket server', (done) => {
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 0 }, () => {
      const socket = new Socket()
      socket.connect(`ws://localhost:${(wss.address() as WebSocket.AddressInfo).port}`);

      socket.socket.on('open', () => {
        expect(socket.socket.readyState).toEqual(WebSocket.OPEN);
        socket.socket.close();
      });

      socket.socket.on('close', () => wss.close(done));
    });
  });

  test('should throw error if already connected websocket server', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(2);
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 0 }, () => {
      const socket = new Socket();
      socket.connect(`ws://localhost:${(wss.address() as WebSocket.AddressInfo).port}`);

      socket.socket.on('open', () => {
        expect(socket.socket.readyState).toEqual(WebSocket.OPEN);
        expect(() => socket.connect(`ws://localhost:${(wss.address() as WebSocket.AddressInfo).port}`)).toThrowError('Socket is already connected')
        socket.socket.close();
      });

      socket.socket.on('close', () => wss.close(done));
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74062437/socket.test.ts (10.964 s)
  74062437
    ✓ should connect the websocket server (31 ms)
    ✓ should throw error if already connected websocket server (6 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 socket.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.784 s
```

package versions:

```json
"ws": "^8.9.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3"
```

Comment: They are testing the library itself so there it makes a bit more sense to do that (though they setup the server with the same library? Maybe also not very clean... what if the server part is broken?)

Comment: What implementation details (of ws?) am I testing?